# how to display the active status element alone in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def action(request):

    user = request.user
    typelist=Types.objects.filter(user=user.id,parent_type_id__isnull=False)
              .order_by('title')
    types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None).order_by('title')
    report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
    if 'is_active' in request.POST:
        if types.is_active == True:
             types = Types.objects.filter(
               user=user.id, parent_type_id=None).order_by('title')
                  typelist=Types.objects.filter(
                    user=user.id,parent_type_id__isnull=False).order_by('title')
     return render(request, 'incident/action.html',
        {
            'newreport_menu': True,
            'types':types,
            'checked_ones':checked_ones,
            'typelist': typelist,
     })
```

In models,title field is used save the parent element and child element,if a child element is saved ,parent_type_id field will save the appropriate id of parent element.So now i can able to take all parent element and child element into display.

But some condition is their,that is if the values in is_active field is True,it should display the True values alone,now it is showing all.

I tried the above code ,it is not giving any error but not working.

Thanks

Comment: Please post working code. This code won't even run, because `types` is a queryset and doesn't have an `is_active` attribute (inside the request.POST block).

Comment: But that code still isn't valid. `types` is a queryset. `if types.is_active == True` will always fail with an `AttributeError`.

Comment: One more time before I officially give up: querysets do not have the attributes of their models: they *contain* model instances which have those attributes. `types` is a queryset, not a model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a QuerySet as an object, which is faulty.

What you wanted to do in the first place is to accept one more parameter to your QuerySet.
So you could filter on what came from your `request.POST`

```
Types.objects.filter(..., is_active=True)
```

Views.py

```
def what(request):
    report = Report.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    if 'is_active' in request.POST:
        types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None, is_active=True).order_by('title')
    else:
        types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None, is_active=False).order_by('title')
        typelist = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id,parent_type_id__isnull=False).order_by('title')
    return render(request, 'incident/what.html',
        {
            'newreport_menu': True,
            'types':types,
            'checked_ones':checked_ones,
            'typelist': typelist,
     })
```

I simplified your code some.

Comment: lmelights,i am facing a problem in my application i was explained it in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592136/add-image-to-all-check-box-django could you please have a look and help me in solve this.Thanks